# Building an empty board

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I would like to create a board of all `False` boolean values.

```
Build_empty_board(size):
```

Given positive integer values for the size of a board, create a list of lists
of booleans that has `False` values at each location (representing empty cells).

Examples:

```
build_empty_board(2) → [[False, False], [False, False]]

build_empty_board(1) → [[False]]
```

So far I have this:

```
def build_empty_board(size):
    size = int(size)
    ans = []
    for i in size:
        ans = False
        ans += 1
    return ans
```

I'm pretty sure this is fundamentally wrong, but it's the closest thing I have to a code. Could someone guide me on how to code this correctly?

Comment: I won't write the code for you, but here are two hints: (1) You will need two nested `for` loops with your approach since the board is 2 dimensional, (2) To extend a list, read about `.append()` method.

Comment: I would say you need to review your course materials. That code won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Suppose `size = 3`, `[False for x in range(size)]` will create `[False, False, False]`, and `[[False for x in range(size)] for x in range(size)]` will create `[xxx, xxx, xxx]` where `xxx` stands for `[False, False, False]`. So the final result is `[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]`

```
def build_empty_board(size):
    ans = [ [False for x in range(size)] for x in range(size) ]
    return ans
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide some explanation for what is obviously a homework question? And remove the unnecessary parts while you're at it?

Comment: This comes up with indentation errors any possible fix?

Comment: @Jessica I fixed it.

Comment: @Yunhe are you sure? The coding is the same and says "unindent does not match any outerindentation level"

Comment: make sure you use the same indentation format. If you use 'Tab' as indentation, all indentations should be 'Tab' or 'Tab's. If you use space as indentation, say 4 spaces, make sure no 'Tab' as indentation or 5 spaces as indentation.

Answer (score 0):

First create an empty array of dimension [size,size] using numpy.empty . Then replace each element by False.

```
from numpy import*
def build_empty_board(size):
    ans=empty([size,size])
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            ans[i][j]=False
    return ans
```

build_empty_board(3)